# PHP/PDO Greater than or equal to operator after query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently implementing a follow system using PHP and PDO. The code determines if the button "Follow" or "Unfollow" should show based on the inserted data. The database is updating correctly but for some reason the greater than or equal to operator is not working properly, or I'm not querying the database properly. (Not sure which) Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

In followon.php:

```
if($row['userID']  && $row['userName']){
    if($row['userID']!=$user_id){
        $follow_userid = $row['userID'];

        $stmt = $user_follow->runQuery("SELECT id FROM following WHERE user1_id=':user_id' AND user2_id=':follow_userid'");
                $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id,":follow_userid"=>$follow_userid));
                $follow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(!$follow >= 1){

            $stmt = $user_follow->runQuery("INSERT INTO following(user1_id, user2_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
                $stmt->bindValue(2,$follow_userid);
                $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $user_follow->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET following = following + 1 WHERE userID = ?");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
                $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $user_follow->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET followers = followers + 1 WHERE userID = ?");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$follow_userid);
                $stmt->execute();

                }

        header("Location: index.php?id=".$currentID);
      }
}
```

In followoff.php:

```
if($row['userID']  && $row['userName']){
    if($row['userID']!=$user_id){
        $unfollow_userid = $row['userID'];

        $stmt = $user_unfollow->runQuery("SELECT id FROM following WHERE user1_id=':user_id' AND user2_id=':unfollow_userid'");
                $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id,":unfollow_userid"=>$unfollow_userid));
                $follow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if($follow >= 1){

            $stmt = $user_unfollow->runQuery("DELETE FROM following WHERE user1_id= ? AND user2_id= ?");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
                $stmt->bindValue(2,$unfollow_userid);
                $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $user_unfollow->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET following = following - 1 WHERE userID = ?");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
                $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $user_unfollow->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET followers = followers - 1 WHERE userID = ?");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$unfollow_userid);
                $stmt->execute();

                }

        header("Location: index.php?id=".$currentID);
      }
}
```

And in index.php (where button appears):

```
if($user_id){
                if($user_id!=$id){

                    $query2 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT id FROM following WHERE user1_id=':user_id' AND user2_id=':id'");
                                        $query2->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id,":id"=>$id));
                                        $query2result = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if($query2result >= 1){
                                                echo "<a href='followoff.php?id=$currentID' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>Unfollow</a>";

                    }
                    else{

                        echo "<a href='followon.php?id=$currentID' class='btn btn-info btn-xs'>Follow</a>";

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `$query2result` is __array__. How it can be greater then 1? What do you compare here?

Comment: You're using prepared statements with placeholder values, and that's great, but remember placeholders *should not have surrounding quotes*. Those are added by the database driver if they're considered necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to test the result set with an ID, `$query2->fetch` returns an associative array.

You need to access the field in the result set...

```
if($query2result['id'] >= 1){
```

If you just want to say if a row has not been returned, it will return `false`.

```
if($query2result !== false){
```

Comment: Neither of those solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($query2result);` to see what it contains.